# How can I specify content-type accepted when requesting a HTTP resource with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, content-type, open-uri

I have always used open-uri, and open("").read to get content through http. I am using this to access an API, and now I need to specify that what content type is accepted. They provide this example from curl

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842
```

How do I do this with open-uri or another Ruby function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the optional options hash of open, e.g.

```
open("http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842","Accept" => "text/bibliography; style=bibtex"){|f| f.each {|line| print line}}
```

yields a result.

See also http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html